# Updating ListView Button in single row without notifyDatasetChanged() in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom `ListView` with `BaseAdapter` which contains buttons,`ImageView` and `SeekBar` in each row depending on the device.I want to update the status based on the value that is received.
To update the view the code is

Roomactivity

```
public class RoomActivity extends Activity 
{
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

    }
   public static void receivedvalue(String receivedvalue)
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if(RoomActivity.active==false)
        {

        }
       else  
       {            
            if(id.equals(received[1]))
            {
                customadapter.updateListView(i,status,device);  
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

customadapter

```
class customadapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter
{

   public static void updateListView(int position, String status, String device) 
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     View convertView =listview.getChildAt(position);
     if(list.contains(device))
     {                                  
            SeekBar bar = (SeekBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dimmerseekBar);
            bar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(status));      
     }
     else
     {          
        ImageButton  switchingactiveicon = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.switchingactiveicon);
        switchingactiveicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.redled);

     }    
  }
}
```

The status is getting updated with `SeekBar` but when i try to set the image it is giving expection as `viewimplecalledfromwrongthread`.
How will i resolve this and why is this issue coming. can anyone help me,i tried with different forms but didn't work.

Comment: could you tell me where do you call this method from?

Comment: It is called from main activity

Comment: If activity is active iam calling this method

Comment: Yes,of course,But are you calling it from the UI thread? or is it from a background thread like a n/w operation

Comment: call your adapter again instead notifydatasetchanged() in android

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: it works with seekbar but not with imageview or buttonview . what would be the mistake that i have done

Comment: What is the wrong that i have made in my code. why only seekbar is working and not with other view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your adapter again when you want to refresh , then it will work

for example,

```
 private DataAdapter dataAdapter;
        _dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(Activity.this);                 

    if (_dataAdapter != null) {
        DayList.setAdapter(_dataAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: ok call this adapter on  onRestart(), method in acitivity. @sup

Comment: I do not want to restart the activity,i want to make change only in the view on the listview

Comment: when something is received in roomactivity it should just trigger the image or button background

Comment: but you have to refresh listview. and it will refresh all content you have set so what you need to do is while calling adapter again dont refresh other items make it static. just change image and button.

Comment: Based on my code can you help me how to make the change in my code

Comment: you just want to update SeekBar ? and not button and imageview ? is that so ?

Comment: Thankyou very much for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that one row alone.
Just Leave the android too refresh the view. 
That is, under getView method do assignment values to the controls.

Declare listview public

```
public List<T> listview;
```

Assign updated value from activity or fragment. And call `adapter.Notifydatasetchanged();`

Answer (score 0):

For updating a single list item you have to get the view at the specified position, and then update the view.

You can get list_item using the following method,

```
public View getViewByPosition(int position) {
        final int firstListItemPosition = filesListview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + filesListview.getChildCount() - 1;
        if (position < firstListItemPosition || position > lastListItemPosition) {
            // return filesListview.getAdapter().getView(position, filesListview.getChildAt(position), filesListview);
            return null;
        } else {
            final int childIndex = position - firstListItemPosition;
            return filesListview.getChildAt(childIndex);
        }
    }
```

The above the method will return the view if the View at the given position is visible in the listview otherwise it will return null. For example if the list view contains 20 elements and currently listview is showing 0-6 elements then above method will return the views for 0-6 and others will return null.

```
   View viewByPosition = getViewByPosition(position;
    // If the retrived view is not null then udpate the view otherwise ignore.
    if (viewByPosition != null) {
       //Update the view
    }
```

Hope this will help you!